# How to have vertical x labels?

Tags: matlab, plot

**Soft Question:** How to edit the x label in a bar graph to be vertical in Matlab? 
Here is an example of the x-axis I would like to have
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to get the handle of the axis first. Then you can edit the X axis Tick rotation property which is zero by default. By setting this parameter to 90, it will rotate your x-axis like your picture.

```
h = gca; % handle for current axis
h.XTickLabelRotation = 90; % rotate the tick label
```

Comment: Or just `set(gca,'XTickLabelRotation',90)`.